# Wordpress Search Form - Replace "Search" text with icon

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying do a few customizations to the wordpress default search form and I would like to replace the text "Search" in the value="Search" string with an icon.

Currently I have the following form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="//example.com/">
<div class="box">
   <div class="container-1">
      <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
      <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

How can I put in the following icon instead? `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`

Comment: I do not believe you can put html into the `value` attribute. You could set it to use the font-awesome font-face and enter in the entities of the search icon though. Or you could set the font-face and then use `content:` css property to add the entity,

Comment: I just replace the input type="submit" to button type="submit" and deleted the value completely .. Apart from few styling issues it seems to work fine ..

Answer (score 9):

Here is a bit of a workaround, I replaced the `input` with `button`, removed `value` completely

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="//example.com/">
<div class="box">
   <div class="container-1">
      <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
      <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
           <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>   
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Form seems to work just fine ..

Comment: cant make one character edits but the `<button>` is self closing in that snippet, but also has an end tag